# create and update multiple MongoDB documents in one call

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Let's imagine that I have a MongoDB collection like so:

```
[
{someId: 1, someProp: prop1, isOpen: true},
{someId: 2, someProp: prop1, isOpen: true},
{someId: 3, someProp: prop1, isOpen: true},
{someId: 4, someProp: prop1, isOpen: true},
]
```

I want to make a call to it with an array of objects, but some of these objects will be new, and some will need to override existing documents.

So let's say my array looks like this:

```
[
{someId: 1, someProp: prop1, isOpen: true},
{someId: 2, someProp: prop1, isOpen: true},
{someId: 5, someProp: prop1, isOpen: true},
{someId: 6, someProp: prop1, isOpen: true},
]
```

How do I write a MongoDB query that does the following.

If `someId` matches an object in my second array, just change the `isOpen` to `false`. 
If `someId` doesn't match any objects then insert them into collection.

So after I run my query i would end up with:

```
[
{someId: 1, someProp: prop1, isOpen: false},
{someId: 2, someProp: prop1, isOpen: false},
{someId: 3, someProp: prop1, isOpen: true},
{someId: 4, someProp: prop1, isOpen: true},
{someId: 5, someProp: prop1, isOpen: true},
{someId: 6, someProp: prop1, isOpen: true},
]
```

Is it a good idea to call a `forEach()` and just use:

```
db.books.update(
   { item: "ZZZ135" },
   {
     item: "ZZZ135",
     stock: 5,
     tags: [ "database" ]
   },
   { upsert: true }
)
```

...in the loop? Probably not. That would mean multiple calls to the db. Is there a more efficient way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need [**`bulkWrite`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#bulkwrite_bulkWrite) operation with `upsert`

```
const array = [
    {  someId: 1, someProp: prop1, isOpen: true  },
    {  someId: 2, someProp: prop1, isOpen: true  },
    {  someId: 5, someProp: prop1, isOpen: true  },
    {  someId: 6, someProp: prop1, isOpen: true  }
]


Model.bulkWrite(
  array.map((data) => 
    ({
      updateOne: {
        filter: { someId: data.someId },
        update: { $set: { isOpen: false, someProp: data.someProp } },
        upsert: true
      }
    })
  )
})
```

Will give you the output

```
[
  {  someId: 1, someProp: prop1, isOpen: false  },
  {  someId: 2, someProp: prop1, isOpen: false  },
  {  someId: 3, someProp: prop1, isOpen: true  },
  {  someId: 4, someProp: prop1, isOpen: true  },
  {  someId: 5, someProp: prop1, isOpen: true  },
  {  someId: 6, someProp: prop1, isOpen: true  }
]
```