# How to update many documents with one query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have many documents like that:

```
{_id: 1, data: {a: 989, b: 732}},
{_id: 2, data: {a: 943, b: 778}},
{_id: 3, data: {a: 932, b: 768}},
```

And I want to update any document but with one query. For example, I want to set `{a: 1, b: 1}` for `_id: 1`, than `{a: 2, b: 2}` for `_id: 2` and so on.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail as to exactly what you want the outcome to be? Why are you paticularly interested in mixing all the updates together? - if you ar using Node.JS you could create an array of update promises and then perform a Promise.all(update_promises); to excecute all of the updates as quickly as possible and without waiting for the previous ones to complete before starting the next one

Comment: I want to see: 
{_id: 1, data: {a: 1, b: 1}},
{_id: 2, data: {a: 2, b: 2}},
after update

Comment: I have 1000+ document and I don't want to make 1000+ queries

Comment: If you did an array of promises using Promise.all() this would return an array of the returns once they are all complete

Comment: are 'a' and 'b' related to the id or are they different for every id?

Comment: @matthew257 I got it. I can create many queries and than execute Promise.all([..]) but I try to understand Can I do it without 1000+ queries.

Comment: any document has its own {a, b}

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can't do this in one command - the documentation doesn't suggest you can do this either

Comment: @dakiesse Do you want add any kind of filter and then update the documents which qualifies that particular filter?

Comment: You need to use `bulkWrite` operation here.

Comment: Possible dupe of [mongoose add multiple object to array if not exist based on key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801033/mongoose-add-multiple-object-to-array-if-not-exist-based-on-key/51808332#51808332) and [create and update multiple MongoDB documents in one call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51882718/create-and-update-multiple-mongodb-documents-in-one-call/51882836#51882836)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it with `bulkWrite`

```
collection(`someCollection`).bulkWrite([
  {
    updateOne: {
      filter: {_id: 1},
      update: {$set: {'data.a': 1000, 'data.b': 800}},
    }
  },
  {
    updateOne: {
      filter: {_id: 2},
      update: {$set: {'data.a': 1001, 'data.b': 801}},
    },
  },
  // ...
])
```