# MongoDB update multiple rows in a single query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection with the following document

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "item" : "item1",
   "stock" : 184
}
{
   "_id" : 2,
   "item" : "item2",
   "stock" : 330
}
{
   "_id" : 3,
   "item" : "item3",
   "stock" : 140
}
```

I want to update this collection like this using a single query.

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "item" : "item1",
   "stock" : 80
}
{
   "_id" : 2,
   "item" : "item2",
   "stock" : 60
}
{
   "_id" : 3,
   "item" : "item3",
   "stock" : 170
}
```

I can do it using `forEach` but I have to update thousands of records at once which will time consuming. So does MongoDB have this functionality?

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you have some array of new stock values for each item, or are you increasing all stock values in the same amount?

Comment: @marmor I will be having updated array of stock values. I am not increasing all stock values in same amount for that example I did that. Btw updated the question :)

Comment: I think this is what you were looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51882718/create-and-update-multiple-mongodb-documents-in-one-call/51882836#51882836

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [bulk operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) in nodejs via [`Collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/unordered.html)

```
var bulkOp = yourCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

bulkOp.find({ _id: 1 }).updateOne({ /* update document */ });
bulkOp.find({ _id: 2 }).updateOne({ /* update document */ });
// etc

bulkOp.execute();
```

You can build it however you need to and then have the database do it all at once.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. Removed `await` as `bulkOp.execute()` is not an async function.

Comment: [`execute`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/UnorderedBulkOperation.html#execute) (and actually most mongodb driver functions) has two forms: results are either returned through a callback parameter, or, if no callback was provided, will return a promise (that can be awaited)

Answer (score 2):

You can't perform the changes you want using a single request.

What you can do is :

---

**Having small amount of data**

Launch one request for each change to perform

```
await Promise.all(entries.map(x => model.findOneAndUpdate(...)));
```

---

**Having a large amount of data**

Use cursor to handle the data by packs.

```
const cursor = await model.find({
   _id: {
      $in: idsEntries,
   },
}).cursor().exec();

await handleCursorRead(cursor);

handleCursorRead(cursor) {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
       cursor.eachAsync((x) => {
           x.stock = ...;

           x.save();
       }, {
          // How many items do we look at same time
          parallel: 250,
       }, () => {
          // When we are done processing all items
          resolve();
       });
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Even more concise way**

Array you want to update with

```
const array = [{
    "_id" : 1,
    "item" : "item1",
    "stock" : 80
}, {
    "_id" : 2,
    "item" : "item2",
    "stock" : 60
}, {
    "_id" : 3,
    "item" : "item3",
    "stock" : 170
}]
```

Query to for bulk update

```
Model.bulkWrite(
  array.map((data) => 
    ({
      updateOne: {
        filter: { _id: data._id },
        update: { $set: { stock: data.stock } }
      }
    })
  )
})
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer Anthony. I just wanted to know which one is faster this one or `initializeUnorderedBulkOp`?

Comment: Both are bulk queries. So both will work in a similar way. It is just simplified way of above query.

Comment: Both are bulk queries. So both will work in a similar way. It is just simplified way of above query.